# View drops 20 pixels when build against iOS 6 SDK in Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, uiview, uisplitviewcontroller, ios6, xcode4.5

After building my iPad app against iOS 6.0 SDK, I get this weird behavior with my UISplitViewController's detailed view.  The detailed view is positioned 20 pixels (points / 40 pixels) lower than it should be.

[image]

Here is what it looked like under 5.1:

[image]

For DetailViewController_iPad.xib in Interface Builder I've set the Simulated Metrics > Top Bar to None.  This didn't help.
I've logged the view frame:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
//.. etc
NSLog(@"viewDidLayoutSubviews: %@", CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(self.view.frame) );
}
```

This logs the height as 684 instead of the what it should be: 704.

`Height = 684;`  `Width = 703;` `X = 0;` `Y = 0;`

Anyone have any experience with this sort of thing?  What should I try next?

**UPDATE:** This problem seems intermittent, with some compiles causing it, and some not.

If anyone else has had this problem and found out what causes it, I'd still be keen to know.

Comment: I got a similar problem but with my UIView background image. I have 20 pixel available on the bottom.

Comment: Have you set your autoresizing mask correctly? (flexible height, fixed top and bottom border)

Comment: @deanWombourne Yes I've done that, to no avail.

Comment: Can you build a demo project and put it say on DropBox so we can play with it. Don't need anything in the split views - just a project that shows the problem. I just created a new project in Xcode4.5 for iOS6, it works perfectly of course. Maybe take your original project and remove all the unnecessary items.

Comment: Are you using a xib or storyboard?

Comment: If this is still vexing you, and you are targeting 6.0, you might consider exploring the new Auto Layout functionality - it's kind of throwing a dead chicken at the problem, but it might get you past this situation.  However, only an option if you are targeting 6.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the exact same issue!

The issue will occur when there is another view controller in the navigation controller and this split view controller is pushed in the method *application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:* during app launch.

This fixed the problem for me:

When pushing the *splitViewController* I used

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:splitViewController animated:NO];

})
```

instead of

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:splitViewController animated:NO];
```

I used this only for iOS6 otherwise first view will be momentarily showed in OS < iOS6.

Comment: Just had a similar problem on the iPhone in iOS 6 (iOS 5 was fine) where modals pushed into the Navigation Controller at launch would not display behind the translucent status bar. This solved it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're not doing anything to effect the frame of the view in code, correct? It's the view's controller that's doing all the layout? If so, have you tried tinkering with `-wantsFullScreenLayout`?

> When a view controller presents its view, it normally shrinks that view so that its frame does not overlap the device’s status bar. Setting this property to YES causes the view controller to size its view so that it fills the entire screen, including the area under the status bar. (Of course, for this to happen, the window hosting the view controller must itself be sized to fill the entire screen, including the area underneath the status bar.) You would typically set this property to YES in cases where you have a translucent status bar and want your view’s content to be visible behind that view.
>
> If this property is YES, the view is not resized in a way that would cause it to underlap a tab bar but is resized to underlap translucent toolbars. Regardless of the value of this property, navigation controllers always allow views to underlap translucent navigation bars.
>
> The default value of this property is NO, which causes the view to be laid out so it does not underlap the status bar.

Mind you, `-wantsFullScreenLayout` should really only effect a window's root view controller. So if this fixes your problem (and you're not doing anything goofy with your view controller hierarchy), please file a bug with Apple!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `[UIViewController statusBarHidden]` is set to `NO` on your detail controller?

Comment: @MattyG It was worth a try. 20px always look like something with the status bar.

Comment: yeah thanks for that.  I agree, it seems status bar related too.  That's why I tried removing the simulated metrics status bar.  I'm not sure how to go forth diagnosing the problem now.

Comment: there is no property on a VC to set the statusbar - that's UIApplication.  agree probably status bar related.  do you have any code-based changes to status bar hidden property anywhere in your code?  if you always want the status bar, there's no reason to have that (since it's the default), and use the plist value to make the status not be initially hidden.

Comment: @RobReuss Oh, you are right. I don't know how I could see it in the docs. I have probably clicked to a different class by mistake :) I hope simulated metrics in xib are not causing this...

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4.5 has a habit of applying autolayout, which may be the cause of some of your grief - inspect this and trying deselecting it.

Comment: autolayout is not selected.  Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

have you set autosizng property of height in xib file or programmatically, if yes try removing them and see if it helps the problem.

Answer (score 0):

May help.
I was also affected with same issue i had just reduce size of view in my example:
I have 480px height in XIB for iPhone Apps and i reduce it to 460px.
Please same do for iPad not sure but may help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when i tried to present another viewcontroller in ViewWillAppear method. I got it solved by moving my presentViewController code to ViewDidAppear method. Hope it will help.